# Beanstalk: ebextensions customization fails with service: command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to install an application through .ebextensions in my elasticbeanstalk stack. I've followed the doc here for [advanced environment customization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). This is my config:

```
files:
  "/tmp/software.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      wget https://website.net/software/software-LATEST-1.x86_64.rpm
      software-LATEST-1.x86_64.rpm
      sed -i -e '$a\
      *.* @@127.0.0.1:1514;RSYSLOG_FileFormat' /etc/rsyslog.conf
      /sbin/service rsyslog restart
      /sbin/service software start
container_commands:
  01_run:
    command: "/tmp/software.sh"
```

When applying the config I receive an error that the command "service" is not found even though I point to the location of the service command in /sbin/service. I've tried a lot of different things but I always get this error. Running the script manually on the host works without any issue.

The image the stack is using is Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)

The specific error message is:

```
[3744211/3744211]\n\n/tmp/[01;31m[Kalert[m[K_software.sh: line 8: service: command not found\n/tmp/[01;31m[Kalert[m[K_software.sh: line 9: service: command not found. \ncontainer_command 02_run in .eb[01;31m[Kextensions[m[K/[01;31m[Kalert[m[K-software.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":127,"events":
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My co-worker tried to install the software a different way and it worked. This is what worked:

install.config >>

```
  01_install_software:
    command: rpm -qa | grep -qw software || yum -y -q install https://website.net/software/software-LATEST-1.x86_64.rpm
  02_update_rsyslog:
    command: sed -i -e '$a*.* @@127.0.0.1:1514;RSYSLOG_FileFormat' -e '/*.* @@127.0.0.1:1514;RSYSLOG_FileFormat/d' /etc/rsyslog.conf
  03_restart_rsyslog:
    command: service rsyslog restart
```

services.config >>

```
services:
  sysvinit:
    rsyslog:
      enabled: "true"
      ensureRunning: "true"
    software:
      enabled: "true"
      ensureRunning: "true"
```